# Migratory aptitude in pinacol pinacolon rearrangement

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Out of *ortho*-methoxyphenyl and *para*-methoxyphenyl which one has more migratory aptitude in pinacol-pinacolon rearrangement?

Answer (score 1):

Groups with higher electron density have a greater tendency to migrate. So, o-methoxy phenyl should be the answer but due to steric factors p-methoxy phenyl can always be an equally likely answer.  It can only be found out accurately by experimentation and considering other reaction conditions.